# Key down event handler running multiple times in Swift

Tags: swift, nsevent

I am trying to do something when a given key is pressed in a macOS App. First, I ran into a problem where the `keyDown` event was detected multiple times on each press, therefore executing the handler multiple times. As per a suggestion, I added code to check whether the event is a repeat and it seemed to work at the time. However, this solution seems to work only some of the time, other times the event is getting detected multiple times. Also, I can't seem find a pattern in situations when it works and when it doesn't.What might be the problem and how could I fix it.
Code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: checkKeyDown(event:))
    }

    func checkKeyDown(event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent{
        if event.isARepeat == false{
            if event.keyCode == 36{
                print("Hello World!")
            }
        }
        return event
    }
```

Comment: Is `viewDidLoad` executed once?

Comment: Yes. It's executed only when the app launches.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the event monitor when the window closes seems to have fixed this issue.

```
var numKeyDown : Any?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        numKeyDown = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .keyDown, handler: checkKeyDown(event:))
    }

 override func viewWillDisappear(){
     if let numMonitor = self.numKeyDown {
        NSEvent.removeMonitor(numMonitor)
     }
 }

    func checkKeyDown(event: NSEvent) -> NSEvent{
        if event.isARepeat == false{
            if event.keyCode == 36{
                print("Hello World!")
            }
        }
        return event
    }
```

Comment: So `viewDidLoad` is executed more than once?